# Excel 2007 - Pivot Tables and Multiple Text Values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm creating a pivot table in Excel 2007. What I'm trying to show are 4 columns, the first being the device names of a list of computers, the second being the corresponding device serial number. Where I'm having trouble is getting the serial number to show in my pivot table as a value, not a column heading or row heading. I want a column that says "serial number" and the list of corresponding values, not a count or sum.

Anyone know how to do this??

Comment: I have some images as examples. let me know if you'd like some and I can send them to you.

Comment: This isn't really what Pivot Tables are designed for.  They're designed to help aggregate data, which is why you're getting sum and count options. It sounds like your looking for something more like a report-writer would produce.  If you post some sample data, you may be able to bend Excel to do what you want-so yes the images would be helpful.  You can post a link to an image sharing site, or you can type some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the "Device Name" and "Serial Number" in the Row Labels section of the Pivot Table Field List form, and choose the "classic" pivot table layout, you'll get this.  Is this what you're looking for?

[image]